# Three.js + WebVR set "height" of camera viewing position

Tags: three.js, webvr

Developing in **ThreeJS r87** using the [standard example WebVR script](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/vr/WebVR.js). Got a 3D scene successfully rendering in VR through Chrome on my phone with a Google cardboard.

When I am using VR the camera/viewer's point of view is at the centre of the world (0, 0, 0). The floor plane runs horizontally across my line-of-sight and I am looking up at all the objects.

I have tried to change the point of view of the VR headset using:

```
camera.position.set(0, 15, 0);
```

But it just seems to ignore/override it.

Is the position just always fixed now? Do I need to put all my scene objects in a group and move it around to create the effect of my user moving/flying around the scene?

Looking through the ThreeJS library I can see that concepts such as user height exists in other headsets: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/VRControls.js#L58 But support for them seem to be flaky too.

I dug deeper beyond ThreeJS to [VRDisplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRDisplay) and found things like VRDisplay.getPose() to get an instance of [VRPose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VRPose) but that's in the process of being deprecated and I'm not sure why?

Explanation and solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the camera in a group?

```
var user = new THREE.Group();
user.position.set( 0, 15, 0 );
scene.add( user );
user.add( camera );
```

[See from Line #60 here.](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webvr_vive.html#L60)